# twilio Message tag not working

Tags: message, twilio, twilio-twiml

Why is this failing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Message>
        <Body>Store Location: 123 Easy St.</Body>
        <Media>https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png</Media>
    </Message>
</Response>
```

I am receiving the following error:

Warning: 12200 - Schema validation warning

Parse error found on line 1 of the Raw Response

https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/calls/CA7920533e98ffed29426d29e7e27746c8

I did a diff with the original example, and it's EXACTLY the same!

Original example is listed here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message

Answer (score 2):

I looks like you are building your application with Twilio as a Voice call application instead a SMS Message application.

The url https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/calls/CA7920533e98ffed29426d29e7e27746c8 suggested that you are accesing your application as a voice call application, if not it would be https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/**messages**/{some other id}.

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  Just to add to this, today its not possible to use the <Message> verb within a TwiML response to a Twilio Voice request.  Its only allowed in TwiML responses to Message requests.  You can however use the <Sms> verb in response to a Voice request, which lets you tell Twilio to send a Text messages while handling a voice call.  Hope that helps.